# Convert Response JSON to csv - R

Tags: r, json, httr

Im trying to read a csv file from the following link

"http://wbes.srldc.in/ReportFullSchedule/ExportFullScheduleInjSummaryToPDF?scheduleDate=01-06-2020&sellerId=af6f9733-6351-48c5-a1d5-9cdb2d841fb7&revisionNumber=50&getTokenValue=1567874357957&fileType=csv&regionId=4&byDetails=0&isDrawer=0&isBuyer=0"

The problem is server has blocked web scraping. I could download only using GET method by specifying a user agent. But now im not able to convert the reponse to csv

The following is my response

Response [http://wbes.srldc.in/ReportFullSchedule/ExportFullScheduleInjSummaryToPDF?scheduleDate=01-06-2020&sellerId=af6f9733-6351-48c5-a1d5-9cdb2d841fb7&revisionNumber=50&getTokenValue=1567874357957&fileType=csv&regionId=4&byDetails=0&isDrawer=0&isBuyer=0]
  Date: 2020-05-31 23:26
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/csv
  Size: 6.47 kB

Im a beginner trying to learn R. Can Anyone help?

Comment: See the `fromJSON()` function from the "jsonlite" package.

Comment: *"server has blocked web scraping"* usually indicates a **policy** against scraping. To me, this precludes any ethical discussion of how to scrape their data, whether using `rvest` or `httr::GET` or anything in a programming language (which all, to some or all extent, satisfy the label of "scraping").